# compiler error while creating trigger in sql developer;

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have two tables:

```
create table superheroes('sh_name varchar2(30));
create table sh_audit(new_name varchar2(30), old_name varchar2(30), username varchar2(30), entry_date varchar2(30), operation);
```

trigger:

```
create or replace trigger SUPERHEROES_AUDIT
before insert or update or delete on superheroes
for each row
enable
declare
    v_user varchar2(30);
    v_date varchar2(30);
begin
    select user, TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,' DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') INTO v_user, v_date from dual;
    if inserting then
        insert into sh_audit(new_name, old_name, username, entry_date, operation)
        values(:NEW.sh_name, null, v_user, v_date,'insert');
    elsif deleting then
        insert into sh_audit(new_name, old_name, username, entry_date, operation)
        values(null, :OLD.sh_name, v_user, v_date,'delete');
    elsif updateing then
         insert into sh_audit(new_name, old_name, username, entry_date, operation)
         values(:NEW.sh_name, :OLD.sh_name, v_user, v_date,'update');
    end if;
end;
/
```

> error:  Trigger SUPERHEROES_AUDIT compiled Errors: check compiler log
>   Error(5,5): PL/SQL: Statement ignored Error(11,11): PLS-00201:
>   identifier 'UPDATEING' must be declared.

Comment: What's `UPDATEING` ?comment?

Comment: and what is unclear in this error? updatEing ??

Comment: There's no E in `updating`.

Comment: it's an elsif condition

Comment: it's typing mistake thanks

Comment: `SELECT...INTO vars...FROM DUAL` makes for unclear code. Better to use simple assignment, e.g.`v_user := user;` and `v_date := TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,' DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');`. Also, in `create table superheroes('sh_name varchar2(30));` there should't be a `'` before `sh_name`.

Comment: You don't even need a separate assignement step, as you can assign a value as part of declaration. https://jolliffe.hk/2018/07/27/please-stop-abusing-dual

Answer (score 1):

try separating the trigger like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_BI_SUPERHEROES_AUDIT
   BEFORE INSERT
   ON SUPERHEROES
   FOR EACH ROW
   ENABLE
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO SH_AUDIT (NEW_NAME, OLD_NAME, USERNAME, ENTRY_DATE, OPERATION)
      VALUES (
                :NEW.SH_NAME,
                NULL,
                USER,
                TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, ' DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
                'insert');
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_BU_SUPERHEROES_AUDIT
   BEFORE UPDATE
   ON SUPERHEROES
   FOR EACH ROW
   ENABLE
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO SH_AUDIT (NEW_NAME, OLD_NAME, USERNAME, ENTRY_DATE, OPERATION)
      VALUES (
                :NEW.SH_NAME,
                :OLD.SH_NAME,
                USER,
                TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, ' DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
                'update');
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_BD_SUPERHEROES_AUDIT
   BEFORE DELETE
   ON SUPERHEROES
   FOR EACH ROW
   ENABLE
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO SH_AUDIT (NEW_NAME, OLD_NAME, USERNAME, ENTRY_DATE, OPERATION)
      VALUES (
                NULL,
                :OLD.SH_NAME,
                USER,
                TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, ' DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
                'insert');
END;
```